# How to solve bigmod where range of n,p,m where (n,p,m)<=10^18

Tags: bigmod

I can solve bigmod if range of m is <=10^9. But if range more than this range my procedure overflows. How can i solve (n^p)%m where (n,m,p)<=10^18

Comment: which programming languange do you use? what did you do to solve bigmod if range is <= 10^9?

Comment: c,c++ . I use recursion to solve bigmod.